# Browser as GUI for user input to a python script

Tags: python

Is there an easy way to use the Chrome as a GUI to allow a user to input data for further processing in Python. What I want to do is :

1. The user enters data into a table. The table is 5 rows by 4 columns. The user data is then processed in JScript and a weight average of each row is displayed in column 5 of the table. The user can then adjust the input data based on what shows up in column 5 or accept it.
2. Assuming the user accepts the data, it is then used in a python script (that is already written) for much more detailed calculations.

The python script is pretty detailed and no something that is easily re-written in JScript.I can prompt the user for each data input but I would prefer to have a simple table where all the data can be entered at once

Newbie here that knows HTML, a bit of JScript and a bit of Python and some R. But not ready to take on GUI programming in TK, QT, GTK, Kivy....etc.

What is the easiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask for this.

You can make a python server, and process all the inputs in python. 
Here is a great tutorial to start flask

[Flast tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSrZ6r7hwdM)

Comment: Many thanks for the comments and suggestions. I did take a look at Flask but I found it a bit overwhelming. I got through the beginning of the video 1 and thought it looked good unit the app didn't work and  the speaker had to go back and make corrections. I found the corrections way above my head. I might be able to plow through it with some work. But I was looking for something that was a little more simple. The degree of complexity associated with Flask seemed to be on par with GUI programming. 

Again, I greatly appreciate the suggestion but it may be above my level.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a web framework (Flask seems like the simplest to recommend for your case) and implement your page as a view (whose GET request implements a view that sends the JS and web form to the browser, and whose POST request implements a view that does the detailed calculations and sends the final response).